# Quickest/Most efficient way to get available times for Scheduler Database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm creating a database that I want to use to schedule tasks for random 2-hour windows each day within a given date and time range.  For instance, Task1 may run from 1 Jan to 12 Jan anytime between the hours of 5am and 5pm.  Therefore, the database will schedule the task for a random 2-hour window (to start no earlier than 5am and stop no later than 5pm) on each of those days.  It may throw out something like this for Task1:

```
   Date      Start_Time      Stop_Time
  01 Jan        06:32          08:32
  02 Jan        14:24          16:24
  03 Jan        08:05          10:05
  04 Jan        12:17          14:17
  05 Jan        11:23          13:23
  06 Jan        12:53          14:53
  07 Jan        09:11          11:11
  08 Jan        05:27          05:27
  09 Jan        12:46          14:46
```

In addition to the conditions for each Task (must be scheduled each day within a date range and within the given time range), no more than 2 tasks can overlap at any given point on any day, and no task can run into the next day (therefore they cannot start after 10pm).

So far, my database does this, albeit slowly, so I'm wanting to know if the method I'm using is the most efficient.

For tables, I have one (tblWindows) which basically just consists of a column called WindowStart populated with each minute of the day, starting at 00:00 and ending at 23:59.  Literally, 1440 records -- one record for each minute of the day.

I have another table (tblTaskConfigs) where I have the configs for each task to be scheduled against.  This is where I specify the start/stop dates and start/stop times for each Task to be scheduled.

Finally, my tblSchdTasks table keeps track of when tasks are scheduled.

Regarding the operation, it goes something like this:

```
Open tblTaskConfigs recordset.  For each TaskConfig record:
   1) Save the following into variables:
      - StartDate
      - StopDate
      - StartTime
      - StopTime
   2) For each date the task is to be scheduled on:
      A) Using DCount on tblSchdTasks, check if that task has already been scheduled for that date: 
         - Yes: Skip to the next date
         - No: 
            I) Open a query recordset (qryAvailWin) that contains available windows for that date that fall within the TaskConfig's start/stop times (times from tblWindows in which there are no more than 1 task that overlaps those times).
            II) Choose a random record from qryAvailWin to determine the start time of the Task to be scheduled.
            III) Open a tblSchdTasks recordset and create a new record for the task and it's randomly-selected time for that day.
```

So, I'm opening up the tblTaskConfigs recordset, and looping through each record.  For each of those records, for each day the Task is to be scheduled for, I'm opening up 2 more recordsets (qryAvailWin & tblSchdTasks) to check available times and to actually schedule the task.

For 1 task that lasts 56 days, this operation takes about 108-113 seconds.  I suspect it's because it's opening and closing a total of 113 recordsets (1 + (56 x 2)).  Additionally, qryAvailWin has three parameters (CurrDate, StartTime, and StopTime) that I need to set before each time it's opened so that it only shows available windows that are relevant to that date and that TaskConfig.

Can you think of a more efficient way of doing something like this?

Comment: Does it have to start at a random time? You can make this way more efficient if you start at the first timeslot every day (05:00 AM), and then just append tasks behind the first task of that day. If you want, you can also insert gaps between tasks

Comment: Yep, unfortunately it has to be a random time -- that's the nature of our work.  Unfortunately, I also can't go into specifics of *why* they have to be random times.

Answer (score 0):

Had some time to spare, so I coded my approach to the problem.
Since you're not giving me much to work with as to specifics, you will have to fill in a lot of blanks, such as variable names and WHERE criteria.

First, 2 helper functions for picking random numbers and dates:

```
Public Function RandomRange(Lower As Double, Upper As Double, Optional IncludeDecimals As Boolean = True) As Double
    'Returns a random number between Lower and Upper, either with or without decimals
    RandomRange = Lower + (Rnd() * (Upper - Lower + IIf(IncludeDecimals, 0, 1)))
    If IncludeDecimals = True Then Exit Function
    RandomRange = Int(RandomRange)
End Function

Public Function RandomTime(Lower As Date, Upper As Date) As Date
    'Returns a random time between Lower and Upper
    Dim randomTimeDbl As Double
    randomTimeDbl = CDbl(Lower) + (Rnd() * CDbl(Upper - Lower))
    RandomTime = CDate(randomTimeDbl)
End Function
```

Then, the actual logic to schedule tasks for an interval of days:

```
Public Function ScheduleTasksBetweenDays(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, TaskIdentifier As Variant)
    'Open the scheduled tasks table
    Dim rsSchdTasks As Recordset
    Set rsSchdTasks = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblSchdTasks SORT BY Date ASC, Start_Time ASC")

    'Second recordset for tasks only on a specific date
    Dim rsFiltered As Recordset

    'Create a collection to save valid start and end dates
    Dim startEndDates As Collection
    'And create a collection for overlapping times
    Dim overlappingTimes As Collection

    'Create two arrays to save start-end date pairs
    Dim startEndDatePair(2) As Date
    Dim previousTaskStartEndTime(2) As Date
    'Create an int to hold random values
    Dim randomInt As Integer

    'Make an iterator for a while loop, and one for the for loop
    Dim dateIterator As Date
    Dim i As Integer
    dateIterator = StartDate
    'Iterate through all the dates
    While dateIterator < EndDate

        'Set rsFiltered to all records of that date
        rsSchdTasks.Filter = "Date = #" & Format(dateIterator, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
        'Open the filtered recordset
        Set rsFiltered = rsSchdTasks.OpenRecordset()

        'Use the already instantiated recordset instead of a DCount, if the task is already set, next iteration
        rsFiltered.FindFirst "TaskIdentifier = " & TaskIdentifier
        If Not rsFiltered.NoMatch Then GoTo NextDate
        'Start at the first already set taks, iterate through them
        rsFiltered.MoveFirst
        'Clean up the overlappingTimes collection
        Set overlappingTimes = New Collection
        'Initialize the first task as the previous one
        If Not rsFiltered.EOF Then
            previousTaskStartEndTime(1) = rsFiltered.Fields("Start_Time")
            previousTaskStartEndTime(2) = rsFiltered.Fields("End_Time")
            rsFiltered.MoveNext
        End If
        Do While Not rsFiltered.EOF
            'If the start time of the next task is less than the end time
            If previousTaskStartEndTime(2) > rsFiltered.Fields("Start_Time") Then
                'The overlapping segment is from end of previous to start of new
                startEndDatePair(1) = rsFiltered.Fields("Start_Time")
                startEndDatePair(2) = previousTaskStartEndTime(2)
                'Add those that interval to the collection of invalid intervals
                overlappingTimes.Add startEndDatePair
            End If
            previousTaskStartEndTime(1) = rsFiltered.Fields("Start_Time")
            previousTaskStartEndTime(2) = rsFiltered.Fields("End_Time")
            rsFiltered.MoveNext
        Loop
        'Now, we have a collection of all times that can't overlap with the task

        'Lets set the next collection of possible start times

        'First possible start time is 5 AM
        startEndDatePair(1) = #5:00:00 AM#
        'Open up a blank collection of possible valid intervals
        Set startEndDates = New Collection

        'Next step seems familliar, loop through the invalid times to calculate the valid ones
        For i = 1 To overlappingTimes.Count
            'If the start of the next task is more than 2 hours away than the possible start time, we can plan it before this task
            If startEndDatePair(1) + #2:00:00 AM# < overlappingTimes(i)(1) Then
                'Set the maximum start time to 2 hours before the next task
                startEndDatePair(2) = overlappingTimes(i)(1) - #2:00:00 AM#
                'Add it to the collection of possible times
                startEndDates.Add startEndDatePair
            End If
            'Set the next possible valid interval to be behind this task
            startEndDatePair(1) = overlappingTimes(i)(2)
        Next i
        'All unchanged since last edit here

        'Check if we can put our task behind the last one, if so, last possible start time is 10 PM
        If startEndDatePair(1) < #10:00:00 PM# Then
                'Set it's maximum end time
                startEndDatePair(2) = #10:00:00 PM#
                startEndDates.Add startEndDatePair
        End If

        'Now, we have an array with all possible intervals where our task can start at
        If startEndDates.Count = 0 Then
            'Apparently, this day is already full and we can't plan the task. Do something adequate for that scenario
            GoTo NextDate
        End If

        'pick a random interval from our intervals array
        randomInt = RandomRange(1, startEndDates.Count, False)

        'Assign our array to that interval
        startEndDatePair(1) = startEndDates(randomInt)(1)
        startEndDatePair(2) = startEndDates(randomInt)(1)
        'update the schdTasks table
        rsSchdTasks.Edit
        rsSchdTasks.AddNew
        rsSchdTasks.Fields("Date") = dateIterator
        'Pick a random start time within our interval
        rsSchdTasks.Fields("Start_Time") = RandomTime(startEndDatePair(1), startEndDatePair(2))
        'End = 2 hours later
        rsSchdTasks.Fields("End_Time") = rsSchdTasks.Fields("Start_Time") + #2:00:00 AM#
        rsSchdTasks.Fields("TaskIdentifier") = TaskIdentifier
        rsSchdTasks.Update
NextDate:
        dateIterator = dateIterator + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

As you may note, the improvements include:

- You only open up tblSchdTasks once. Per day you filter the open table and put that into a new recordset
- You no longer use DCount, but instead check the already opened table
- Instead of just picking random times and checking if they are valid, you make a collection of all possible start and end intervals, then pick one of those intervals, then pick a timepoint within that interval
- There is no longer any need for the (imho weird) tblWindows
- You now include seconds in your start and end dates
- You no longer need qryAvailWin, which was searching a giant table and probably taking up a lot of your time
- You've gone from opening 113 recordsets and executing 56 DCounts (which are just as heavy as recordsets) to opening 1 recordset, and filtering and searching it 56 times

And a possible disadvantage:

- If the intervals are really unequal in size (one is long, another is short) they both have an equal chance to be picked for the tasks. This isn't too hard to fix, but well, I've put in enough effort I think

Comment: Thank you!  I will give this a look through when I have time and reply back with any feedback and questions.  Thank you again for your time and effort -- it is really appreciated!

Comment: Oh, and note that you could make it more efficient by just skipping the filtering altogether, and just assuming the sort put everything in the right order, doing a `.FindFirst` to start at the first record for the start date, and going from there.

Comment: I think I might not have been clear enough, my apologies.  When I said, "no more than 2 tasks can overlap at any given point on any day" what I meant was there can't be any point in any day where more than 2 scheduled tasks overlap each other.  
  
Take for example my original post, if Task1 was randomly scheduled on 1 Jan for 06:32-08:32 and then later we created a Task2 that was randomly scheduled on 1 Jan for 07:45-09:45.  Those two taskings will overlap each other between 07:45-08:32.  Later, I need to schedule Task3 which will also have to run on 1 Jan; 07:45-08:32 will be unavailable.

Comment: Ah, didn't get that. Is the length of all tasks 2 hours, or is it variable?

Comment: All tasks are always two hours.

Comment: Edited it to allow 2 tasks to overlap, but not 3 at the same time.